# How do I parse XFBML tags when rendering a EmberJS view?

Tags: javascript, facebook, xfbml, ember.js

I have an EmberJS view that dynamically renders XFBML tags. How can I get that view to call FB.XFBML.parse() whenever the EmberJS view is being rendered?

Is it a good idea to override the View.afterRender() method, and call FB.XFBML.parse() then? If so, how do I get the EmberJS ? It is currently set to undefined for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your view's didInsertElement() method will be called after your view has been inserted into the DOM. I don't have experience with XFBML, but I imagine this will work in your view:

```
  didInsertElement: function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
  }
```